# how to grep special character "$"

Tags: shell, grep

I have tried following two ways to grep for "$". However, both of the ways are unsuccessful. How can I grep special character in xterm ?

```
grep -Fr "ABC_$" me.txt
```

xterm output :- Illegal variable name.

```
 grep -Fr "ABC_\$" me.txt
```

xterm output :-Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Use single quotes and escape it once: `grep -r 'ABC_\$' me.txt`. Not sure you need `-F` here. Well, in my grep (*grep (GNU grep) 2.25*) `grep -F "ABC_$"` also works well.

Comment: Why are you using the recursive flag (`-r`) if you're searching in a single file? This being said, I can't reproduce this. Do you have grep set to an alias that breaks argument quoting? What's `type grep` for you?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus That shouldn't make a difference here, though.